# Transitioning when encountering an error in Ember

Tags: ember.js

I am trying to do `this.transitionTo('route name')` in the `ApplicationRoute` error action.

What seems to happen is when I click on the link, it hits the error, and doesn't transition to the target route, it seems to say it's transitioning to the route it was just in again. This is using `{{#link-to}}` so I have a feeling there is some magic going on in there...

I am trying to use [this example](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#toc_code-error-code).

The error is happening in the `model()` method on the route (which is using jquery and returning a promise [`jqXHR`]) because I am returning a 401 http code.

Is this not correct?

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend(
    actions:
        error: (error, transition) ->
            if error.status == 401
                @transitionTo('login')
)
```

Another thing I've tried is setting the `.ajaxError` method and transitioning in there but the result seems to not transition either.

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend(
    setupController: (controller, model) ->
        route = @
        Ember.$(document).ajaxError((event, jqXHR, ajaxSettings, error) ->
            if jqXHR.status == 401
                route.transitionTo('login')
        )

        controller.set('content', model)
)
```

Has anyone got this working on ember 1.2.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was an issue on my end. I had some extra logic that was essentially countering my transition! Whoops!

Answer (score 3):

Try returning `true` in your error hook, to bubble the error event.

From the documentation (http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/asynchronous-routing/#toc_when-promises-reject):

```
actions: {
  error: function(reason) {
    alert(reason); // "FAIL"

    // Can transition to another route here, e.g.
    // this.transitionTo('index');

    // Uncomment the line below to bubble this error event:
    // return true;
  }
}
```